# Grep the text which matches with a pattern

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I was looking for a command which will print the selected portion of a line which matches the conditions.
Eg, my text line is like this:

```
p1=X||p2=Y||p3=X||p4=X||p5=X||p6=Y||p7=X
```

I want to print those values that have have `Y`. With this example, the expected result is `p2,p6`.

Comment: Do you want to print `p2,p6`, or `p2` newline `p6`, or `p2=Y` newline `p6=Y`? If there was `p8=YZ`, would you want to print `p8`?

Answer (score 8):

Using `P`erl compatible regular expression in `grep`:

```
grep -Po '..(?==Y)' <file
```

Result:

```
p2
p6
```

Comment: and the code golf winner is ...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
echo 'p1=X||p2=Y||p3=X||p4=X||p5=X||p6=Y||p7=X' | grep -o '[^|]*=Y' | cut -d= -f1 | sed -e 'N;s/\n/,/g'
```

Output:

```
p2,p6
```

Answer (score 3):

`awk` can read records based on a regex delimiter of your choice. eg `'[|\n]'`
It can also split records into fields on the delimeter of your choice. eg. `'='`
The ternary operator `(condition)?:` prevents a leading comma.

```
awk -F= -vRS='[|\n]' '$2=="Y"{ printf (i?",":"")"%s", $1; i=1 }'
```

output:

```
p2,p6
```

If a trailing newline is needed, it can be appended in the `END{}` section. To prevent a newline being output when there are no matches, the Output Record Separator (`ORS`) can be initially set to *none*, and then set to `\n` if a match is found.

```
awk -F= -vRS='|' -vORS= '$2=="Y"{printf (ORS?",":"")"%s", $1; ORS="\n"} END{print ""}'
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
tr '|' '\n' | sed -n 's/=Y$//p'
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple awk

```
awk -F\| '{for (i=1 ; i<= NF; i++) 
    if ( $i ~/Y/ ) { split($i,A,"=") ; printf "in %d : %s\n",i,A[1] ;}}'
```

where

- `-F\|` use `|` as separator
- `{for (i=1 ; i<= NF; i++)`  scan through pattern
- `if ( $i ~/Y/ )` if found
- `{ split($i,A,"=") ; printf "in %d : %s\n",i,A[1] ;}` split it and print it

output

```
in 3 : p2
in 11 : p6
```

use `printf "%s\n",A[1]` to skip pattern number

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -nE 'say join(",",/(\w+)=Y/g)'
```